# Visual Studio says package is not imported, but pip says it is already imported

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio, windows-10, psycopg2

I am on VIsual Studio Code and the first line looks like this:

```
import psycopg2
```

The *"import"* keyword is underlined in red and when I hover a mouse pointer over it I see the error *"Unable to import psycopg2 pylint(import-error)"*.

But if I open terminal in the same directory where my project file is located and use pip to install the package I see confirmation that the package is already installed:

```
PS C:\Python Projects\database> pip install psycopg2
Requirement already satisfied: psycopg2 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (2.8.2)
```

Also, I don't get any error message when I issue *"import psycopg2"* command in interactive Python shell.

So, when I try to run my code, I get this:

```
PS C:\Python Projects\database> python script2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script2.py", line 48, in <module>
    create_table()
  File "script2.py", line 9, in create_table
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE store IF NOT EXISTS (item TEXT, quantity INTEGER, price REAL)")
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "IF"
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE store IF NOT EXISTS (item TEXT, quantity INTEGE...
```

Could this be a Visual Studio issue?

Comment: Are you sure Visual Studio is pointed at the right interpreter (i.e. c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\...)?

Comment: Thank you, VS was indeed pointing to the wrong interpreter